# Ramsey number problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> Let $K_{n}$ is the complete graph on $n$ vertices and $T_{m}$ is a tree on $m$ vertices
>
> How do I show that $R(K_{n} , T_{m}) = (n-1)(m-1) + 1$?

Here $R(G,H)$ is the minimum $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that every $2$ coloring of edges of $K_{t}$ yields a red $G$ or a blue $H$, for graphs $G,H$. I was thinking of using induction but I am stuck.

Comment: Are you certain it's an equality? If yes, can you find a graph of $ (n-1)(m-1)$ vertices that doesn't contain a $K_n, T_m$?

Comment: Yes, I believe you have to find a 2 coloring of $K_{(n-1)(m-1)}$ such that it has no red $K_{n}$ or blue $T_{m}$.

Comment: Can you add that construction into the question? It can help motivate what "structure avoider" we need.

Comment: Induction on $m$ works. What have you tried? If you show your work, I'd undelete my solution.

Comment: @Calvin, why would the single edge be connected to the $T_m$?

Comment: @Empy2 Argh, good point.This doesn't work yet. Let me revisit.

Comment: Note that $T_m$ is not some $m$-vertex tree of your choosing; it is an arbitrary given tree on $m$ vertices. What has to be proved, then, is that any red/blue coloring of the edges of a complete graph on $(m-1)(n-1)+1$ vertices either contains a red $K_n$ or else contains a blue copy of **every** $m$-vertex tree. E.g., if $m=3$ and $n=4$, the result to be proved is $R(K_3,P_4)=R(K_3,K_{1,3})=7$.

Comment: Do you have access to that paper?

Comment: @CalvinLin The construction is trivial.  Start with a red $K_{n-1}$.  Then inflate each vertex of this red $K_{n-1}$ so that each vertex becomes a blue $K_{m-1}$ (the edges between vertices from different $K_{m-1}$ subgraphs are still red).

Comment: @Batominovski Yes, that's the construction in my deleted answer. The point of my question is to have OP show their work, which currently is completely missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original source of this result seems to be a one-page note of Václav Chvátal, Tree-complete graph Ramsey numbers, *J. Graph Theory* 1 (1977), 93. I haven't seen Chvátal's note, but I suppose his argument is something like the following.

The inequality $R(K_n,T_m)\ge(n-1)(m-1)+1$ is trivial; there is an obvious red/blue coloring of the edges of a complete graph of order $(n-1)(m-1)$ with no red $K_n$ and no blue tree of order $m$.

I have to show that $R(K_n,T_m)\le(n-1)(m-1)+1.$ Let me restate it this way:

**Theorem.** If $G$ is a graph of order $r=(n-1)(m-1)+1$ with independence number $\alpha(G)\lt n$, then $G$ contains an isomorphic copy of every tree of order $m$.

We can assume that $n\gt1$. Since
$$\chi(G)\ge\frac r{\alpha(G)}\ge\frac r{n-1}\gt m-1,$$
we have $\chi(G)\ge m$, and so $G$ contains a minimal $m$-chromatic subgraph $H$, which has minimum degree $\delta(H)\ge m-1$. Thus it will suffice to prove the following:

**Lemma.** If $H$ is a graph with minimum degree $\delta(H)\ge m-1$, then $H$ contains an isomorphic copy of every tree of order $m$.

The lemma is easily proved by induction on $m$. Maybe it's a theorem or exercise in your graph theory textbook; e.g., it's Proposition 2.1.8 on p. 70 of Douglas B. West's *Introduction to Graph Theory*, Second Edition.